# How to track WooCommerce coupons outside of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, coupon, discount

Sometimes I'm giving coupons to my customers to share the coupon, and when coupon usage is reached to for example 10, I give them special discount. But I want them to track the coupon usage without signing in to my wordpress dashboard. Is there any way to do that. (If coupon usage is trackable with code I can program it but I can't find the code).

Comment: Do you want to limit how many times a coupon can be used? Per user or at all?

Comment: No sir. I want to give my subscriber an unlimited coupon to share that coupon with his/her social media. And every time that coupon usage is reached to 10 I want to give my subscriber that shared that coupon a special discount. But main issue here is the person that shared coupon want to track coupon usage. But it should be outside of wordpress woocommerce dashboard. Can he/she see coupon usage outside of my website. Is there any api, plugin or can I do that with woocommerce function or any other way. Please help. Thanks